# Convert a numpy int64 into a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I want to transform a numpy int64 array

```
Zed           49
Kassadin      39
Cassiopeia    34
RekSai        33
Nidalee       30
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

into a list like this:

`[(Zed, 49), (Kassadin, 39), (Cassiopeia, 34), (RekSai, 33), (Nidalee, 30)]`

Till now I've tried:

`l = l.tolist()`

`l.T`

and

`[row for row in l.T]`

but the output looks like this:

`[49, 39, 34, 33, 30]`

Comment: That's a Pandas series, not a NumPy array.

Comment: What is data type of l?? Is it a dictionary?

Comment: I just did it but it still giving me the same result deleting the names

Comment: @cerofrais l is dtype:int64

Comment: @cerofrais I created it with this code `l = ban15_sp_eu.value.value_counts()[:5]`

Comment: Lol that's a pandas series then, first answer, L = [(k, v) for k, v in l.items()] should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is list comprehenstion:

```
L = [(k, v) for k, v in series.items()]
```

Or convert values to DataFrame anf then to list ot tuples:

```
L = list(map(tuple, series.reset_index().values.tolist()))
```

Or to `MultiIndex`:

```
L = series.to_frame('a').set_index('a', append=True).index.tolist()
```

---

```
print (L)
[('Zed', 49), ('Kassadin', 39), ('Cassiopeia', 34), ('RekSai', 33), ('Nidalee', 30)]
```